# Python 3 filtering directories by name that matches specific pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, directory, filtering

Currently I'm developing script that will perform cleanup of specific directories.

For example:
Directory: /app/test/log
contains many sub-directories with name pattern testYYYYMMDD and logYYYYMMDD

What I need, is to filter out only directories like testYYYYMMDD

To get all folders with absolute path that are in given directory I use:

```
folders_in_given_folder = [name for name in os.listdir(Directory) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(Directory, name))]
folder_list = []
for folder in folders_in_given_folder:
    folder_list.append([os.path.join(Directory, folder)])
print(folder_list)
```

Gives output:

```
[['/app/test/log/test20150615'], ['/app/test/log/test20150616'], ['/app/test/log/b'], ['/app/test/log/a'], ['/app/test/log/New folder'], ['/app/test/log/rem'], ['/app/test/log/test']]
```

So now I need to filter out sub-directories that fits pattern,
pattern can be something like: *test*, test*, test2015*

I've tried using glob.glob(), but this seems to work only with files not directories.

Could someone please be so kind and explain how I could achieve desired outcome?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import os 
import re

result = []
reg_compile = re.compile("test\d{8}")
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(myrootdir):
    result = result + [dirname for dirname in dirnames if  reg_compile.match(dirname)]
```

As advised I will explain (thanks for the -1 btw :D)

the `compile("test\d{8})` will prepare a regex that matches any folder named `test` followed by a date with a 8 numbers format.

Then I take advantage of the `os.walk` method to have every folder properly in the `folders` iterator (thus avoiding using the method `is_dir`)

With the line `[dirname for dirname in dirnames if  reg_compile.match(dirname)]` I filter the folder whose name matches the regular expression explained above.

For a first answer (yes it was the first) that works (tested on my computer for python2 and python3) I find it harsh to be downvoted. Also the accepted answers contains the same kind regular expression I used. Now I also agree that I should have had explained earlier.

Would you be kind enough to remove that downvote ?

Comment: Please try explaining what you did instead of just pasting code snippets as an answer - that way, the OP (and anybody else) will be able to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use re module. re module is regexp python module.
`re.compile` creates re object and you can use match method to filter list.

```
    import re
    R = re.compile(pattern)
    filtered = [folder for folder in folder_list if R.match(folder)]
```

As a pattern you can use smth like this:

```
>>> R = re.compile(".*test.*")
>>>
>>> R.match("1test")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x024ED800>
>>> R.match("1test")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x024ED598>
>>> R.match("test2015")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x024ED800>
>>> R.match("1test2")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x024ED598>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct  8 2014, 13:08:17) 
>>> import re
>>> re.match(r'.*/[^/]*test[^/]*$', '/app/test/log/test20150616')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 26), match='/app/test/log/test20150616'>
>>>
```

Regular expression `r'.*/[^/]*test[^/]*$'` means matching any path that ends with `/*test*` where `*` as anything except `/`.